# Wait until Fragment's `onCreateView()` method completes before interacting with it from parent Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, user-interface, android-fragments, listener

I have the following Fragment which displays a MapView.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private MapView mapView;
    private Location currentLocation;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.onResume();

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        // Move My Location button to bottom right
        View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(1).getParent()).findViewById(2);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
                googleMap = gMap;
                googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources().getString(R.string.map_style)));

                if (!checkPermission())
                    askPermission();        // NOT WORKING PROPERLY
                if (checkPermission()) {
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    zoomToCurrentLocation();
                }
                //else handle no location permissions

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void zoomToCurrentLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        if (checkPermission())
            currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        googleMap.animateCamera(zoomTo(15));
        googleMap.moveCamera(newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if(location != null) {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    googleMap.animateCamera(zoomTo(15));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) { }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) { }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) { }
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    public void disallowInteraction() {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    }

    public void allowInteraction() {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
    }

    private void askPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 1);
    }
}
```

It will be added to several Activities, and depending on the activity, I want to set different UI elements to be active or not within the MapView - these elements are turned on or off in `allowInteraction()` and `disallowInteraction()`.

Currently, when I try to call these methods from the parent Activity's `onCreate()` method as:

```
mapFragment = (MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.workoutActivityMap);
mapFragment.allowInteraction();
```

the app crashes. I would assume this is happening because the `googleMap` instance variable of the Fragment hasn't entered the `OnMapReadyCallback()` yet. How can I call these methods from the parent Activity, but only once the Fragment will allow them to be called?

**EDIT**

MapFragment.java

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private MapView mapView;
    private Location currentLocation;
    FragmentListener fragmentListener;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.onResume();

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        // Move My Location button to bottom right
        View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(1).getParent()).findViewById(2);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
                googleMap = gMap;
                googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources().getString(R.string.map_style)));

                if (!checkPermission())
                    askPermission();        // NOT WORKING PROPERLY
                if (checkPermission()) {
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    zoomToCurrentLocation();
                }
                //else handle no location permissions
                fragmentListener.onMapFragmentReady();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void zoomToCurrentLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        if (checkPermission())
            currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        googleMap.animateCamera(zoomTo(15));
        googleMap.moveCamera(newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if(location != null) {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    googleMap.animateCamera(zoomTo(15));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) { }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) { }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) { }
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    public void disallowInteraction() {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    }

    public void allowInteraction() {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
    }

    private void askPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof FragmentListener) {
            fragmentListener = (FragmentListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement FragmentListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        fragmentListener = null;
    }

    public interface FragmentListener {
        void onMapFragmentReady();
    }
}
```

fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

WorkoutActivity.java

```
public class WorkoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MapFragment.FragmentListener {

    MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.workoutActivityMap);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapFragmentReady() {
        mapFragment.allowInteraction();
    }
}
```

WorkoutTabFragment.java

```
public class WorkoutTabFragment extends Fragment implements MapFragment.FragmentListener {

    MapFragment mapFragment;

    public static WorkoutTabFragment newInstance() {
        return new WorkoutTabFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_tab, container, false);
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.workoutTabFragmentMap);

        FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton)  view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(WorkoutTabFragment.this.getContext(), WorkoutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapFragmentReady() {
        mapFragment.disallowInteraction();
    }
}
```

Both of the last two classes contain

```
<fragment
    android:name="ie.ucd.runtracker.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/workoutActivityMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>
```

in their XMLs

Comment: Please add the error stack from the logcat.

Comment: I put the solution below

Answer (score 0):

You need to use interfaces/callbacks to know when your fragment finished to load the map, I fixed your code using an interface

This is your Fragment:

```
    public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

        private GoogleMap googleMap;
        private MapView mapView;
        private Location currentLocation;
        FragmentListener mListener;

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

            mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mapView.onResume();

            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            // Move My Location button to bottom right
            View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(1).getParent()).findViewById(2);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);

            mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
                    googleMap = gMap;
                    googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources().getString(R.string.map_style)));

                    if (!checkPermission())
                        askPermission();        // NOT WORKING PROPERLY
                    if (checkPermission()) {
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        zoomToCurrentLocation();
                    }
                    //else handle no location permissions
                    mListener.onMapFragmentReady();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        private void zoomToCurrentLocation() {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            if (checkPermission())
                currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            googleMap.animateCamera(zoomTo(15));
            googleMap.moveCamera(newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    if(location != null) {
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        googleMap.animateCamera(zoomTo(15));
                        googleMap.moveCamera(newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) { }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) { }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) { }
            };

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }

        public void disallowInteraction() {
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        }

        public void allowInteraction() {
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        private boolean checkPermission() {
            return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
        }

        private void askPermission() {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 1);
        }

           @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if (context instanceof FragmentListener) {
                mListener = (FragmentListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement FragmentListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            mListener = null;
        }

        public interface FragmentListener {
            void onMapFragmentReady();
        }
    }
```

This is your Activity

```
    public class YourActivity extends Activity implements FragmentListener {

        @Override
        public void onMapFragmentReady(){
            mapFragment.allowInteraction();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. My app still crashes though. I have one Activity containing the Fragment - `public class WorkoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MapFragment.FragmentListener` - and one other Fragment containing it - `public class WorkoutTabFragment extends Fragment implements MapFragment.FragmentListener`. Does this change your solution since one of the classes is a Fragment too?

Comment: I don't understand , could you update your question with the code that I wrote and tell us which is the error ?

Comment: you just need to implements FragmentListener no your parent activity

Comment: I tried that but AndroidStudio keeps refactoring it to `MapFragment.FragmentListener`. What package do I import for `FragmentListener`?

Comment: This is the package I am using for my Fragment: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: you could move public interface FragmentListener , in a class apart from the fragment. update your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159933/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-kob).